# Differential forms invariant for the flow of a non-complete vector field

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $ M $ be a manifold and let $ X $ be a *complete* vector field on $ M $. A $ k $-form $ \omega $ on $ M $ is said to be *invariant* under the flow of $ X $ (or just *$ X $-invariant*) if $ (\Phi_t)^*\omega = \omega $, where $ \Phi^X\colon \mathbb R\times M\to M $ is the flow of $ X $.

I was wondering if the notion of invariant differential form makes sense even for not-necessarily-complete vector fields.

Given such a field $ X $ one can say that $ \omega $ is $ X $-invariant if
$$
\omega_{\Phi_t(m)}(\mathrm T_m\Phi_t(v_1),\dots,\mathrm T_m\Phi_t(v_k)) = \omega_m(v_1,\dots,v_k)\text{,}\qquad \text{for all $ v_1,\dots,v_k\in \mathrm T_m M $}
$$
where $ \Phi\colon \mathcal D^X\subset \mathbb R\times M\to M $ is the local flow of $ X $ defined on the set $ \mathcal D^X $ of all the pairs $ (t,m) $ for which there is some integral curve at $ m $ defined at least up to time $ t $, $ m\in M $ is an arbitrary point, and $ t\in \mathbb R $ is such that $ (t,m)\in \mathcal D^X $. Here $ \mathrm T_m\Phi_t^X $ is not defined on $ \mathrm T_m M $, but on $ \mathrm T_mU $ where $ U = \{m\in M : (t,m)\in \mathcal D^X\} $ is an open set in $ M $.

I was wondering if this definition makes sense, since I never seen this spelled out in books.

Another (more philosophical) question would be: by restricting to *complete* vector fields are we leaving behind something important? Or it's kinda "safe" to restrict to well behaved fields since the non-well-behaved ones are rather pathological objects?

Comment: What applications do you have in mind? If, for example, you're thinking about how Lie used this to determine an integrating factor of the ODE $\omega = 0$, then all that matters is a local flow.